# C Programming- Scanf not working. Tried adding space, doesnt work

Tags: c, scanf

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     int option;
     char user[50];

    system("COLOR b");

    printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ GLENMUIR HIGH SCHOOL LIBRARY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \n");
    printf("Username:");
    scanf("%c",&user);

    checkPass();
    printf("\n |                          Options Menu                                 |\n");
    printf(" | Check Out Book(1), Return Book(2) , Register(3), Admin Login (4)      |\n");

    printf("Option:");

    scanf("%d",&option); /*compiler ignores this completely*/
```

I tried adding space before %d, but still didn't work. Any solutions for a newb?

Comment: It should have given you few warnings...

Comment: Don't use scanf.  If you just want to read a character, use `getc` or `fgetc` or `getchar`.  To read an integer, use `fgets` and `strtol`.  As a newbie, just avoid `scanf` completely.

Comment: He wants to read a username, so scanf would be correct. But I dont know if he needs to open standard input first and then use fscanf ?

Comment: The last scanf does not work

Comment: I get no warnings

Comment: Then this is *not the code you are compiling*. I see lots of stuff that should produce warnings and errors – missing end brace, no decl for `checkPass`, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems stem from this statement:

```
scanf("%c",&user);
```

The `%c` conversion specifier only reads a *single character* from the input stream, not a *string*.  If you entered a username like `jbode`, only the `'j'` character is read from the input stream - the remaining characters will be read by the *next* `scanf` (or other input) call.

Unfortunately, that next `scanf` call is expecting a sequence of decimal digits due to the `%d` conversion specifier; `'b'` is not a decimal digit, so you get a *matching failure* - `option` is not updated, `'b'` is not removed from the input stream, and `scanf` returns a 0 to indicate that no successful conversion occurred.

The *right* answer is to not use `scanf` to read the username at all, but to use `fgets` instead:

```
if ( !fgets( user, sizeof user, stdin ) )
{
  // EOF or error detected on input, handle as appropriate
}

checkPass();
...
```

If you really want to use `scanf`, though, the right approach would be:

```
if ( scanf( "%49s", user ) != 1 ) // no & operator on user
{
  // EOF or error detected on input, handle as appropriate
}

checkPass();
...
```

You do not need to use the `&` operator when reading a string into an array of `char`.  The *expression* `user` will implicitly be converted ("decay") from type `char [50]` to `char *`, and the resulting pointer value will be the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

From standard [**7.21.6.2**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12) under the conversion specifiers and their meanings:

> `s`
>   Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.286) If no l length
>   modifier is present, the corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the
>   sequence and a terminating null character, which will be added
>   automatically.

Well as an alternative to `scanf` you can try looking at `fgets`.

So the answer will be `scanf("%s",user);` or more correct use would be `scanf("%49s",user)`. To get a more elanorate idea of why you should consider `fgets` over `scanf` read through this [**discussion**](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Also there is no need to put space before `%d` format specifier because as per standard [**7.21.6.2**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p8)

> Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function)
>   are skipped, **unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier**.

Apart from the change mentioned above check the return value of `scanf`.

```
if( scanf("%49s",user) != 1){
  fprintf(stderr,"You have given wrong input - use input just a word\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

In your case if you have given wrong input then this would fail and you will get the error message.

You can use `%d` specifier in `scanf` like this, no need to provide `' '`.

```
if( scanf("%d",&option)!= 1){
   /* handle error. Put appropriate meaningful error message. */
   exit(1);
}
```

Also in Dev-cpp try to add compiler flags `-Wall -Wextra` that will show you warnings.

- Go to Tools -> Compiler Options
- Now in `general` tab under `Adds the following command when compiler is called` and -Wall -Wextra`and press`OK`,=.

Compile it. You will get some error like this - [Warning] format `%c` expects argument of type `char *`, but argument `2` has type `char (*)[20]` [-Wformat=]`

`&user` denotes an pointer to an array of `char`s containing 20 char. But as mentioned above you have to pass `char*` as second argument to `scanf`.